# How to count users per group assuming many-to-many relation?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have two tables `users` and `groups`, as well as a third table that defines many-to-many relationship `users_groups`:

**Table "group":**

```
CREATE TABLE `group` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` date NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `group` (`ID`, `creation_date`, `type`) VALUES
(1, '2017-06-01', 'AAA'),
(2, '2017-06-01', 'BBB'),
(3, '2017-06-01', 'CCC');
```

**Table "user":**

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `surnames` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `birthdate` date NOT NULL,
  `qualification` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `user` (`ID`, `name`, `surnames`, `birthdate`, `qualification`) VALUES
(1, 'xxx', 'xxx', '1989-03-03', 'A'),
(2, 'xxx', 'xxx', '1990-06-15', 'A'),
(3, 'xxx', 'xxx', '1982-06-14', 'B'),
(4, 'xxx', 'xxx', '1988-06-19', 'B'),
(5, 'xxx', 'xxx', '1984-03-12', 'B'),
(6, 'xxx', 'xxx', '1987-12-19', 'C');
```

**Table "users_groups":**

```
CREATE TABLE `user_group` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `user_group` (`ID`, `user_id`, `group_id`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 1),
(3, 3, 2),
(4, 4, 2),
(5, 5, 2),
(6, 6, 3);
```

I need to count the number of users per group and summarize results as follows:

```
ID   creation_date    type   users_count_per_group
1    2017-06-01       AAA    2
2    2017-06-01       BBB    3
3    2017-06-01       CCC    1
```

This is my current query. I get stuck with many-to-many relation, which means that the same user may appear in different groups (though in my sample data all users appear just once per group):

```
SELECT `group`.`ID`, `group`.`creation_date`, `group`.`type`, COUNT(*) 
FROM `group`, `user`, `user_group` 
WHERE `group`.`ID`=`user_group`.`group_id` 
      AND `user`.`ID`=`user_group`.`user_id`;
```

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT   `group`.`ID`, `group`.`creation_date`, `group`.`type`, COUNT(*)  
FROM     `group`, `user`, `user_group`
WHERE    `group`.`ID`=`user_group`.`group_id` AND 
         `user`.`ID`=`user_group`.`user_id`
GROUP BY `group`.`ID`, `group`.`creation_date`, `group`.`type`
```

Note that implicit joins (i.e., using more than one table in the `from` clause) have been considered deprecated for quite some time now. It would be better to use explicit `join` clauses:

```
SELECT   `group`.`ID`, `group`.`creation_date`, `group`.`type`, COUNT(*)  
FROM     `group`
JOIN     `user_group` ON `group`.`ID` = `user_group`.`group_id`
JOIN     `user` ON `user`.`ID` = `user_group`.`user_id`
GROUP BY `group`.`ID`, `group`.`creation_date`, `group`.`type`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT `group`.`ID`, `group`.`creation_date`, `group`.`type`, COUNT(*) 
FROM `user_group`
JOIN `user` on `user`.ID = `user_group`.`user_id`  
JOIN `group` on `group`.ID = `user_group`.`group_id`
GROUP BY `user_group`.`group_id`
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to join in the `users` table to do what you want.  So, the query only requires one join:

```
SELECT g.id, g.creation_date, g.type, COUNT(*) as users_count_per_group
FROM `group` g JOIN
     user_group ug
     ON g.id = ug.group_id
GROUP BY g.id, g.creation_date, g.type;
```

Addition notes:

- `group` is a really bad name for a table, because it is a SQL keyword.  I name tables in the plural, which general avoids this problem.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Backticks make the query harder to write and to read.